# How do you get the most clicked facebook like-buttons on a single domain?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

We have a large website with about 200,000 like buttons spread across the pages of our domain.  I can go to our insights page to get overall number of likes on a particular day, but can we get say the top ten pages that were most liked in a particular day/week/month.  I don't see anything in FQL (at least that I can decipher) that allows one to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Go to http://www.facebook.com/insights/
then click "Insights for your domain" and follow the instructions how to link domain for your profile and you will be able to follow likes. I just find out that cos I have needed that also.

Comment: I want something I can automate via the api rather that what insights will give me.